Azure Databricks autoloader from Queue storage fails - java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: eventType
I am trying to load message from Azure Queue Storage into Databricks. I am referencing this video and this moment in video in specific. I have the same issue as in this question, with the only difference that I am using .format("cloudfiles"). According to the video, that I have linked, published by Databricks this should be possible.
Here is my code:
jschema = '{"fields":[{"metadata": {}, "name":"message","nullable":true,"type":"string"}]}'
schema = StructType.fromJson(json.loads(jschema))

df = (spark.readStream
      .format("cloudfiles")
      .option("cloudfiles.format","json")
      .option("cloudfiles.useNotifications","true")
      .option("cloudfiles.queuename","queue-dev")
      .option("cloudfiles.connectionString","")
      .schema(schema)
      .load() 
      )

streamQuery = (df.writeStream
               .format("delta")
               .outputMode("append")
               .option("ignoreDeletes", "true")
               .option("checkpointLocation","/mnt/datalake/Streaming-test/checkpoint/")
               .start("/mnt/datalake/Streaming-test/data/")
              )

Here is once again the error
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: eventType
Is there anything I am missing? Thank you for all the help in advance.

You need to make sure that, in your storage event subscription, the event schema is set to EventGridSchema. This will create the correct message format for Databricks to read.


I see, sounds reasonable. The workaround (using just blob storage) has already been implemented, but I will try to experiment again with your solution. Thanks for your answer
